How do I link mariadb c++ connector library to my project using cmake?
I'm new to cmake and I'm trying to connect my app with mariadb database, but can't manage to link a library with my project and I'm getting an include error.
[build] ...main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: mariadb/conncpp.hpp: No such file or directory
[build]     4 | #include "mariadb/conncpp.hpp"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.

I installed it using this https://mariadb.com/docs/server/connect/programming-languages/cpp/install/#Windows_Installation_(MSI)
My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(PROJECT_NAME chat)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_library(mariadbcpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mariadbcpp PROPERTY 
IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/Program Files/MariaDB/MariaDB C++ Connector 64-bit/mariadbcpp-static.lib"
INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "C:/Program Files/MariaDB/MariaDB C++ Connector 64-bit/include/")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mariadbcpp)

include directory has to be good, cause if I use this
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "C:/Program Files/MariaDB/MariaDB C++ Connector 64-bit/include/")
, I get different include errors and I know that absolute paths are dirty but I just want to make it work for now.
Edit
Include error occurred because as Botje in the comments said I used set_property() instead of set_target_properties, but now I get the same error as before when I added include directory to my app:
[build] In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MariaDB/MARIAD~1/include/mariadb/conncpp/Driver.hpp:26,
[build]                  from C:/PROGRA~1/MariaDB/MARIAD~1/include/mariadb/conncpp.hpp:24,
[build]                  from ...\main.cpp:4:
[build] C:/PROGRA~1/MariaDB/MARIAD~1/include/mariadb/conncpp/Connection.hpp:26:10: fatal error: Properties.hpp: No such file or directory
[build]    26 | #include "Properties.hpp"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.


set_property sets a single property. You are trying to set two. Did you mean to use set_target_properties?

Yeah... Thank you, but now i have another problem. The same I had while I included include dir directly to my app, I will edit it into my post

as far as I can tell Driver.hpp has never included that particular file and it was updated three years ago. Furthermore such a file has never existed in the mariadb connector code. Did you accidentally add that line yourself?

Also, "linking" is not something you do with header files but to compiled object files.

Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't change any file. Driver.hpp includes Connection.hpp which includes Properities.hpp that doesn't exist in conncpp

Same story for connection.cpp though... What version of the mariadb connector did you install?

C++ connector 1.1.3-GA MS Windows (64-bit x86)
from here https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/cpp-connector

The source repo for that version does contain a properties.hpp

And it looks like properties.hpp is indeed missing from the .msi. Congratulations, you found a bug in a three-year old release :)

I was about to ask you if there is something wrong with the installer... Now I have to learn how to report a bug. There are some more missing files and replacing whole include folder with the one from source fixed everything. Thanks for everything, I would have wasted a lot of time and self-confidence if you were not here :)

Is there a reason you're using a version that is three years old not the most recent 11.3.2 version?

I thought intuitively that if I download the highest number version from connector tab and it says c++ that it would be the newest version. 11.3.2 version has "server" inside its name, and I thought it wouldn't have connector with it, but it does have C connector.
Anyway I'm not sure if the one I downloaded is 3 years old cause it says here
https://mariadb.com/docs/server/connect/programming-languages/cpp/#Latest_Software_Releases
that is has few months and I like the benefits that are in the next paragraph inside that link

Right, sorry. I mixed up the age of that particular file with the age of everything else. ignore what I said :)

np, thanks once more and have a good day :)

It turned out to be a bug in C++ connector 1.1.3-GA MS Windows (64-bit x86) .msi installer and some files inside include directory were missing.
To fix it I replaced include directory inside instalation directory with the one from source: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp/tree/1.1.3
